MultiClassifierDLApproach not transforming every row of my dataset
I am currently working on a multi-output classification task, in order to classify some customers comments into several cateogories. I am using MultiClassifierDLApproach for this task, with already labeled data for training.
I followed this tutorial : https://www.johnsnowlabs.com/mastering-text-classification-with-spark-nlp.
After fitting my pipeline (described below) on my train set, I am transforming my train and test sets with said pipeline. The results are pretty good, but on some rows the column category is empty and I don't have any calculated probabilities for any category.
I was expecting every row to get the probabilities for every category : maybe not selected categories since I have put a treshold at 0.5, but at least values for each category.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tmJYwZKBVZoHtLcuyWtWhsu6nbonKG-S/view?usp=sharing
On this zip you will find a .ipynb recreating the steps I used to create my pipeline, some sample data and their results, and said pipeline already fitted.
The input column is texte_sw, the label is niveau_2_MC, the output is category.
The issue seems to happen uniformly on my data, the time and date, the length or the number of words doesn't seem to be the problem.
The basic structure of my code :
table = spark.table('...')
stop_words = spark.table('stopwords_french')

#Some data cleaning : lower words, get rid of XXXX, get rid of more than 2 spaces and filtering out empty texts
table_1 = table.withColumn('texte_1', F.lower(F.col('texte')))\
    .withColumn('texte_1', F.regexp_replace(F.col('texte_1'), '(x){2,}',' '))\
    .withColumn('texte_1', F.trim(F.regexp_replace(F.col('texte_1'), '( ){2,}', ' ')))\
    .filter(F.col('texte_1') != '')
#Get rid of french stop words that are 3 characters or lower
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol='texte_1', outputCol='vector')
table_2 = tokenizer.transform(table_1)

list_mots_stopwords = [str(x) for x in stop_words.rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x).collect() if len(str(x)) <=3]
remover = StopWordsRemover(inputCol='vector', outputCol='vector_sw', stopWords=list_mots_stopwords)
table_3 = remover.transform(table_2)\
    .withColumn('texte_sw', F.concat_ws(' ',F.col('vector_sw')))

#My pipeline : 
document = DocumentAssembler()\
              .setInputCol("texte_sw")\
              .setOutputCol("sentence")
        
embeddings = UniversalSentenceEncoder.pretrained("tfhub_use_multi_lg", "xx") \
.setInputCols("sentence") \
.setOutputCol("sentence_embeddings")

multiClassifier = MultiClassifierDLApproach()\
              .setInputCols(["sentence_embeddings"])\
              .setOutputCol("category")\
              .setLabelColumn("niveau_2_MC")\
              .setBatchSize(128)\
              .setMaxEpochs(11)\
              .setLr(1e-3)\
              .setThreshold(0.5)\
              .setShufflePerEpoch(False)\
              .setEnableOutputLogs(True)\
              .setValidationSplit(0.1)\
            .setEvaluationLogExtended(True)\
            .setRandomSeed(123)\
            .setOutputLogsPath('...')

train_table, test_table = table_3.randomSplit(weights=[0.75,0.25], seed=123)
pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(train_table)
pipelineModel.transform(test_table).filter(F.size('category.result') == 0).show()

